# Any power of $x$ from $1$ to $n$, inclusive, starts with a $9$

Tags: number-theory

> For any positive integer $n$, prove that we may choose a sufficiently long string of $9$s for a positive integer $x$ so that any power of $x$ from $1$ to $n$, inclusive, starts with a $9$.

I was thinking of using the binomial theorem here since we can say $(1-0.99\ldots 9)^m$ must start with a $9$ if and only if $99\ldots 9^m$ starts with a $9$. I am not sure how to continue here with the binomial theorem.

Comment: As you saw, it is enough to find a (terminating) decimal $y=0.999\dots9$ such that $y^n\gt 0.9$. Logs will do the rest. There are other ways.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Another option for proving the lemma in  André Nicolas' comment is to show that
$$(1 - r)^n \geq 1 - nr$$
for $r > 0$. So, for any $n$, if we choose $r$ such that $nr < \frac{1}{10}$, we have $$(1 - r)^n \geq \frac{9}{10} .$$